# Low-level caching with Django

Tags: django, caching

Instead of caching the whole site, or whole views, I've decided to cache only a few heavy queries, using the low level caching API.

I'm doing something like this

```
key = ...
value = cache.get(key)
if value is None:
    value = ... 
    cache.set(key, value, CACHE_TIMEOUT)
```

It works *almost* as expected (**question 01:** is there a better way to do it?), 
but if I set `CACHE_TIMEOUT` to a big value (`86400`: the db is updated once a day),
it looks that `CACHE_TIMEOUT` is being overrided by something else, and the value is cached just for a few minutes...

(**question 02:**) What am I doing wrong?
Is my timeout too long? 
Or maybe I'm caching too much information? (`value` contains ~ 500-1000 objects, and it's evaluated in 50-60 different pages/keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cache servers (e.g. memcached) are lossy, and newer items will force older items out of the cache. Monitor your cache statistics and modify your configuration and/or behavior appropriately.

Comment: I'm trying with memcached. Do you think I should try something else?

Comment: I think you should monitor your cache statistics to see what needs changing.

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem... I was working with the low level API, without disabling the whole site caching (the 3 middleware classes). It's absolutely right: cache statistics know the truth!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which cache backend you are using nor how you exactly set the timeout, but maybe you're doing wrong (from the [django documentation on caching](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#cache-backend-arguments)):

> > Each cache backend may take arguments. They're given in
> >     query-string style on the
> >     CACHE_BACKEND setting. Valid arguments
> >     are as follows:

- timeout: The default timeout, in seconds, to use for the cache. This 
  argument defaults to 300 seconds (5
- ...

`CACHE_BACKEND = "memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/?timeout=60`

Comment: The value passed in `cache.set()` overrides this.